# Why am I getting this output? (Python, reference equality)

Tags: python

I have a some code:

```
first = ['a','b']
second = first
second.append('c')
print('Test results: ',first == second, first is second)
```

Which returns `Test results:  True True`.
I expected to get `False False`. I thought that because the `second.append('c')` by appending the `'c'`, the two variables stores different objects - meaning `first = ['a','b']` and `second = ['a','b','c']`

Why do I get `True True`?

Comment: You want `second = first[:]` as a copy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clone or copy a list in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python)

Comment: @squiguy Thanks for the suggestion, however I'm not looking to modify my code, I'm just trying to get some understanding on the whole reference equality thing.

Answer (score 3):

Because `second = first` does not make a copy.  It makes `second` and `first` two references to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the issue is in `second = first`, after execution of this statement, there is no new variable or reference created to some other object instead `second` is pointing exactly to the same memory location as `first`. So any changes made in the `second` would ultimately reflected in the `first` as well:

```
first = [1, 2, 3]
second = first
print second
>>> [1, 2, 3]

second.append(4)
print second
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4]

print first
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

To avoid such issues you `deepcopy` to initialize a new list.

```
from copy import deepcopy
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = deepcopy(a)
b.append(4)
print b
>>> 1, 2, 3, 4
print a
>>> 1, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option # 1** - here references are being compared instead the values

```
first = ['a','b']
second = first
second.append('c')
print('Test results: ',first == second, first is second)
## >> result :  it will always return TRUE
```

Here I recommend to use `first is second` for individual array element than on whole array though Python wont stop you from doing that.

**Option # 2** - its more appropriate way

```
print cmp(second, first)
## >> result : it will return 0 i.e. False
```

**Option # 3** - make use of numpy array

```
print np.array_equal(first, second)
## >> result : it will return False too.
```

You can also use **`deepcopy`** as explained by **`ZdaR`** in the answer above.